# JPA Hibernate :: Inheritance of an entity, with additional OneToMany Lists

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA Hibernate/Spring boot to build a web server with MySQL database, and I'm trying to extend a POJO Entity that looks like this, with additional OneToMany Lists.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

     ....Constructors, getters and setters....
}
```

with this basic user entity, I just wanna make a UserInfo entity with additional information about the user's careers.

```
@Entity
public class UserInfo extends User {

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Career> careers;

     ....Constructors, getters, setters......
}
```

And I'm quite confused which inheritance strategy I should choose. I don't think its necessary to make another column or table for this.
Or should I just query twice..?

I'm kinda new to JPA so not sure which is considered as the best practice or design..

**Edit**:

This is how Career entity looks like. Just in case..

```
@Entity
@Table(name="career")
public class Career {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer user_id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String description;

     ....Constructors, getters and setters....
}
```

Since extending User table was meaningless(just in my case), I changed the `User` class like this.

```
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Career> careers;

     ....Constructors, getters, setters......

}
```

Now I'm trying this with Spring Data JPA, and when I try to show the list of Users with their Careers, it is now querying more than 40 times taking about a minute to show the result.

Is this the N+1 problem..? how can I solve this?

Comment: You are currently using association by defining @OnetoMany over your Careers element in UserInfo class. user_id should be present in User table for mapping with id column of  Career table.I don't see a need of inheritance strategy(Its my view though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the error lies within the model itself. Why should `UserInfo` extend `User`? I cannot imagine which attributes or methods the `UserInfo` should inherit from a `User`. Typical inheritances would be "Developer" or "Administrator".

Why don't you add `UserInfo` as a 1:1 relation in your `User` entity? Another option is to omit `UserInfo` and put the `Career`s as a 1:n relation right into your `User`.

To prevent possible n+1 issues on a growing number of `Careers` you might want to change the fetch mode. See below

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Set<Career> careers = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: In case I wouldn't need to query for Career but just User, I thought it's better to make a lighter User entity and a separate UserInfo entity which can be larger.

Comment: In terms of clarity, it is absolutely valid to transfer data from the User entity to a separate UserInfo entity. Regarding your queries, you should leverage the lazy loading strategy of your particular JPA provider.

Comment: If I make a user_info table, it will only have a user_id column which is a foreign key of the user table. 

If I put the Career as a 1:n relation into the User table, wouldn't it make a slower performance when I only need to search for `id` and `name` of User entity? 

I'm confused which would be the right model in this case.

Comment: Using a lazy loading strategy, the careers of the user would only be queried when you access the getter-method. If you don't, Hibernate would not make a JOIN on the career table. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching

Comment: I tried lazy fetching `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` but I think there's an n+1 problem lying there.. it is querying like 40~50 times and took almost a minute just to show a really simple result.

Comment: I'd propose you play around with the fetch mode. SELECT is the default fetch mode in Hibernate 4.x for 1:n relations, which might, as you said, cause n+1 issues. Please see the added code sample in my answer.